# Clase para agregar Slider Menu - swift 4

Tags: ios, xcode, slider, swift4

Quiero crear una clase que pueda invocar desde cualquier momento en mi programa para poder traer a pantalla un slider menu.

Cree una clase llamada MenuV que implementa a NSObject. Esta clase lo que hace es crear un view con un alpha azul y a la vez mostrar un collection view en una parte de la pantalla.

```
import UIKit

class MenuV: NSObject{

let backView = UIView()
let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = .white
    return cv
}()

func showMenu(){
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        backView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        backView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))

        window.addSubview(backView)
        window.addSubview(collectionView)

        collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: window.frame.maxX * -1, y: 0, width: window.frame.width * 0.75, height: window.frame.height)

        backView.frame = window.frame
        backView.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.backView.alpha = 1
            self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

@objc func handleDismiss() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.backView.alpha = 0
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: window.frame.maxX * -1, y: 0, width: window.frame.width * 0.5, height: window.frame.height)
        }
    }
}

override init(){
    super.init()
}
```

}

Todo va de maravilla, cuando creo una instancia e invoco el método showMenu se agrega un view del tamaño de toda la pantalla semitransparente y sale de la derecha un collection view de fondo blanco.

```
 let menuV = MenuV()
 menuV.showMenu()
```

La idea es que una vez que se hace tap sobre el backView se ejecuta el método handleDismiss que debe desaparecer el mismo.

Como pueden ver en el código, estoy utilizando *UIApplication.shared.keyWindow* para poder tener como referencia la pantalla del dispositivo en el uso de coordenadas.

Sin embargo, me estoy dando cuenta que una vez que se agregan las vistas sobre el window, estas se van hasta la parte inferior y el gesto no es reconocido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De primera instancia se me ocurre que debo buscar la manera de mandar estas vistas hasta la parte superior de la pantalla para que comiencen a responder los gestos.

Me estoy basando en el video [How to Create a Slide-In Menu Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kwCfFG5fDA&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JGKdVUtA5xds1zcyzsz7HLj&index=7), al parecer él está usando switf 3, pero no veo lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: prueba con el comando bringSubviewToFront https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622541-bringsubviewtofront?changes=_5

Comment: segui el video y obtuve el mismo resultado que en el video, creo que este comportamiento es el esperado (que el backView y el collectionview esten atras de todas las vistas, asi lo tengo yo como tu captura de pantalla). Tu problema es que cuando tocas el backView el metodo handleDismiss no se ejecuta?

Comment: Es correcto Sergio, es como si no se reconociera el gesture que le asigne al view. Además los elementos del menu quedan innactivos.

Comment: Copie y pegue tu codigo y funciona bien, cuando se hace tap en la vista con fondo azul se oculta

Comment: Me quiero morir, es en serio? No se por qué tengo al impresión de que mi Xcode está haciendo cosas raras. Voy a probarlo en otra mac. 

Por lo pronto lo resolví agregando la vista como un UIViewController y no como NSObject. Cree una una vista Child con addChildViewController; con ello la vista ya pasa a primer plano y responde todo bien.

Comment: Hola @SergioTrejo Acabo de probar en otra mac el código poniendo un solo botón en el ViewController principal, que invoca mi menu de la siguiente manera 

`@objc func showMenu(){
        let menu = MenuV()
        menu.showMenu()
    }`

Afortunadamente el error es constante y no me estoy volviendo loco aun. Obtengo el mismo comportamiento, me puedes decir como lo estas invocando o darme el repositorio de tu ejercicio de prueba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

estuve revisando tu pregunta y encontré una respuesta que publicaron, la probé  y funciona te adjunto la respuesta y la liga.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
lazy var menuV: MenuV = {
    let menuController = MenuV()
    return menuController
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func cambioEstadoBoton(boton: UIButton) {
    print("Entra a cambio de estado")
    menuV.showMenu()
}
}
```

[Stackoverflow respuesta adjunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077539/gesture-recognizer-not-responding)

Saludos

Comment: Cuando vi el código, nunca me imagine que la simple definición del controlador tuviera este efecto. La explicación que dan en la pregunta adjunta es excelente.